# Generating C++ code at runtime, compiling and running it

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, multiplatform

is there a multiplatform c++ compiler that could be linked into any software ?

Lets say I want to generate c++ code at runtime, compile it and run it.
I'm looking for a compact solution (bunch of classes), preferably LGPL/BSD licence :)

As far as I know it can be done in Java and c#. What about c++ ?

Comment: Note that C++ compilation might be slow, so don't expect to be recompiling whole C++ scripts 60 times per second. Also, be ready to add some dependencies to your project.

Comment: Please be aware that Java/C# are running on top of a virtual machine, and C++ needs to be compiled into native code.

Comment: @Bobby: thats not always true, certain java builds are JIT'ed, same goes for C# edit: nevermind, missinterpreted the meaning of that answer...

Comment: Maybe not C++ but for Pure C you can use libtcc (i.e. tiny c compiler as a library) and it's really tiny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd drop C++ altogether and use [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/). If you wanted to use C++ because the people using your app only know this, they should have no difficulties going to javascript.

And it's damn fast. And Javascript is a cool language too.

Comment: I was considering C++ bacause of performance. I wonder how much slower v8 runns js code compared to similar c++ code.

Comment: there is just in time compilation with V8, soou should definitely benchmark. I believe however that the ease of use of V8 will offset the problems you'll encounter if you try to compile C++ code on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

Well maybe one of the modules of [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/) will be of help? It's not dry yet on the C++ side but certainly will be soon.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any open source ones for C++, but if you want small and compact scripting and are not hung up on C++  [LUA](http://www.lua.org/) might be an option for you

Answer (score 2):

I've done this years ago in Linux by generating C++-code into a file, compile it by shell execute (with gcc) and then linking in the generated library dynamically. The dynamic linking differs of course between platforms.

Comment: I did it once too (a parser were taking an equation, and C code was generated on the fly). The problem is that you need a full development environment, which you have to deploy with your application. On linux it is generally not a problem, but on other platforms it is. Moreover, there are security risks with this approach. Imho, scripting is superior, even in situations where you need speed.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is much much harder in C++, because the language doesn't use a virtual machine (or "runtime") that abstracts machine specifics away.

You could look into gcc, it's under the GPL IIRC, and ports exist for all major platforms.

Answer (score 1):

When we looked into scripting we chose AngelScript because of the similarity with C++. 
V8 is great but it's certainly limited to some platforms, AngelScript is a lot easier to compile with and probably to learn (if you came from C++) and it has a zlib license.
http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/